# Spring Data JPA Hibernate - Extra elements appearing in @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have some entity classes which have a one-to-many - many-to-one relationship. I am using Spring and Hibernate.

Each `TwoWayService` has exactly 2 `Service`s in my application.

Excerpts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "two_way_services")
public class TwoWayService  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
               mappedBy = "twoWayService", 
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Service> services;

    public TwoWayService() {    
        services = new ArrayList<>();   
        // Add two as default 
        services.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Service(), new Service()));
    }

    public void setService1(Service service) {
        services.set(0, service);
        service.setTwoWayService(this);
    }

    public void setService2(Service service) {
        services.set(1, service);
        service.setTwoWayService(this);
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn
    private TwoWayService twoWayService;

    public void setTwoWayService(TwoWayService twoWayService) {
        this.twoWayService = twoWayService;
    }

    ...
}
```

I am using Derby on the backend. The database schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE two_way_services (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  config_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(80),
  admin_ip VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  connection_state INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE  services (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  name VARCHAR(80),
  type INT NOT NULL,
  ruleset VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  two_way_service_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (two_way_service_id) REFERENCES two_way_services(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The repository interface:

```
public interface TwoWayServiceRepository extends Repository<TwoWayService, Integer> {
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    ...
}
```

In my unit tests, I find that when I call `findOne` on a `TwoWayService`, I find that I have 4 `Services` instead of 2. Browsing the database directly shows the data as I would expect.

```
TwoWayService tws1 = repo.findOne(1); // get by id
assertThat(tws1.getServices().size()).isEqualTo(2); // fails, expected:<[2]> but was:<[4]>
```

Examining it in the debugger I see 4 elements in the `services` list: the two that I expect, plus 2 extra ones which are copies of the expected. I don't see where these are coming from. Why are these extra objects appearing in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think, it is because you add 2 services in the constructor and 1 in each setter. This makes 4 in total. You test for the amount of services, is that what you wanted to test?

Comment: I am calling `List.set` in the setters, which just replaces the item at the given index. `List.add` would add a new one.  It's weird, elements 0 & 1 in the list are the service1 objects and elements 2 & 3 are the service2 object. I've tried not creating the defaults in the constructor, but same result.